# css relative vs absolute inside of 3 level div

Tags: html, css

So I am testing w/ `absolute vs relative` and for most part, I am beginning to understand. I get that part that when you use `absolute`, and your parent is `relative`, it will use the coordination related to your parent.

Question is, if I wanted to `position` that parent to it's parent.

How should it be?

> [I have this repl which has this implementation](https://repl.it/NHVd).

So basically if I wanted div two to be relative to div one (but div two is already `position:relative` and it is parent to div three which has `absolute`).

How can I make relationship here div one as relative and div two as absolute(but it's already relative).

What is the right thing to do?

```css
#one {
      width:50px;
      height:30px;
      background-color:yellow;
      margin:20px;
      padding:15px;
      top:200px;
    }
    
    #two {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color:red;
      margin:10px;
      padding:10px;
      left:500px;
      top:100px;
      position:relative;
    
    }
    
    #three {
      width:15px;
      height:20px;
      background-color:green;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
    }
```

```html
 
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="one">
          <div id="two">
            <div id="three"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: sorry, did you see the link for the code?

Comment: This question will be useless if your link died, so it would be better to include it in your question, and that is what I mean by no code

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not position here. Your problem is usage of left, and top which position div's specifically at a distance from browser's edges. If I change your css to this, your divs are coming out inside one other.

```css
#one {

      background-color:yellow;
      margin:20px;
      padding:15px;
      top:200px;
       position:relative;
    }
    
    #two {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color:red;
      margin:10px;
      padding:10px;
      position:relative;
    
    }
    
    #three {
      width:15px;
      height:20px;
      background-color:green;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
    }
```

```html
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="one">
          <div id="two">
            <div id="three"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a situation that will require what you are asking for. If there is, I'd like to see an example :).

You can achieve whatever effect you want by placing the second and third `div`'s absolutely to the first one. You know the exact coördinates of the second `div`. By using those you can calculate what the absolute position of the 3th `div` should be.